How to unlock parachain lease after expiration
We ran a Kusama parachain where the node and runtime was pretty ancient. Recently the lease expired and afair, previously the locked amount for the lease was returned to the admin wallet automagically. Now this does not seem to be the case, so the question is, how to unreserve the lease deposit? Or is the only way to completely offboard to deregister the paraId, which does not seem to work via polkadot.js ui anymore (previously worked on one of our Polkadot paraIds)
Thanks!

Could you share your chain's para id? Otherwise, it might take me a bit longer to find the reason for the lock. Did it use crownloan?

Might be related to this https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/issues/4565

Yes, this seems to be related, thanks. The paraId is 2236. At the current point I do not see a way to offboard or purchase coretime.
